Triggering Azure ML Designer Pipeline using CLI
I need help with triggering the already existing Azure Machine Learning Pipeline created on Designer via CLI. The CLI command is to be executed as part of CICD pipeline for Orchestration.

Add more details on what you tried so far.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
